# Where does cython pyximport compile?

Tags: python, cython

My `cython` / `pyximport` code works very well on a read/write filesystem.

But (for testing purposes), I need to try it on a **read only filesystem**.

**How to change the cython / pyximport temporary directory** ? (where does it do the job? i.e. the on-the-fly compilation?)

How to set this "working directory" to somewhere else than the current directory, for example `/tmp/` (which is not `ro`, but `rw`) ?

---

Traceback:

```
!!   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/Cython/Distutils/build_ext.py", line 301, in cython_sources
    self.mkpath(os.path.dirname(target))
!!   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/cmd.py", line 352, in mkpath
    dir_util.mkpath(name, mode, dry_run=self.dry_run)
!!   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dir_util.py", line 76, in mkpath
    "could not create '%s': %s" % (head, exc.args[-1]))
!! ImportError: Building module samplerbox_audio failed: ["DistutilsFileError: could not create '/root/.pyxbld': Read-only file system\n"]
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From `help(pyximport.install)`

> By default, compiled modules will end up in a `.pyxbld`
>   directory in the user's home directory.  Passing a different path
>   as `build_dir` will override this.

so pass `build_dir` as an argument when you call `pyximport.install` to make it use your read/write system.

Answer (score 1):

From Cython documentation [Link](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html)

pass the build_dir argument with a value equals to the path where you want the modules to be compiled and that will override the home directory

[image: docs]

for example

```
pyximport.install(build_dir="/mnt/f/")
```